# monaco-editor: how to trigger backspace

Tags: monaco-editor

I want to emulate keyboard event.
but the code:

`editor.trigger(monaco.KeyCode.Backspace, 'type')`

not work,

it will not delete current char in editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Backspace` key monaco has specific core command called `deleteLeft`:

```
editor.trigger(monaco.KeyCode.Backspace, 'deleteLeft')
```

Comment: thanks a lot!  how about the "enter" key, i just find the  "lineBreakInsert" action.
or is there a good solution to replay what user do with keyboard?

Comment: You can try `editor.trigger(null, 'type' , { text: '\n' })` for `Enter`,